# I am going to show you the sink, kitchen and fridge

Tags: grammar, articles

Can we use one article in

>

- **I am going to show you the sink, kitchen and fridge.**   (the sink and the fridge are in the kitchen we are talking about)
- **I am going to show you the accommodation, campus and school.** (we are talking about a single campus with a dorm and an academic building)

Comment: Your grammar is correct, but your choice of nouns is odd. Why not _the sink, cooker and fridge in the kitchen_?

Comment: As above, you would normally not supply a list of items and have one of those items be of a different type than the rest. In the first example, for instance, you wouldn't normally list everything *inside* a kitchen—but then also count the kitchen itself as one of those items. (And, if you do, it would normally be either the first item or the last item, not one stuck in the middle.) Here, it would be *I am going to show you the kitchen, including its sink, fridge, and oven.* Or *I am going to show you the sink, fridge, and oven that are in the kitchen*.

Comment: Aren't a dorm and an academic building included in a campus? While a campus is but a plot of land, the others are buildings.

Comment: That is the whole point of the above comments. Being shown round the campus would include seeing the academic buildings, student accommodation etc.

Comment: Nevertheless, for some reason, the second sentence didn't raise any questions initially, did it?

Comment: Please use a comma before your *and*. Skipping it drives many Americans to apoplexy and confusion.

Comment: @tchrist Conversely, adding it in drives just as many to apoplexy. You can’t win with serial commas – or without them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Programmers abhor mishmash special-case rules for parsing.

Comment: I meant that the choice of nouns _in both sentences_ was odd; I just used the first as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, the nouns in your first example are not quite related in the right way to justify omitting the articles: instead of *kitchen*, you need to have an item that, like the sink and the fridge, is typically *found* in a kitchen.

I agree with you that the second example is marginally acceptable. It's only *marginally* acceptable because both *campus* and *school* need to be interpreted in a particular way for the sentence to work, and not in the way the overall context most naturally suggests. In the end, to make the sentence work, we interpret *campus* not in the sense in which the *accommodation* and *school* are part of it (that was the problem with *kitchen* in your first sentence), but rather as something like *the grounds*, i.e. what the open areas and the exteriors of the buildings look like. *School* is also a bit iffy; to make the sentence work, I think our mind tries to interpret it as a particular *building*.

**Discussion**

According to [*Collins COBUILD English Guides: Articles*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0003705617), articles can be left out

> when two nouns (or adjectives), both acting as head of a noun group, are joined together with 'and' or 'or'; the second head can be without its article. This happens with both the definite and the indefinite article.
>
> *They had enhanced **the reliability and quality** of radio reception.
>
>   …**a coffee cup and saucer.**
>
>   You can order traveller's cheques through **a local bank or travel agent.***
>
> You don't have to leave out the second article; you can say 'a coffee cup and a saucer'. But if you do leave it out, the two nouns must be closely related in meaning; you couldn't say 'There was a matchbox and jacket on the table'.